# What is the time and space complexity of a Scala's head/tail extractor?

Tags: scala, tail-recursion, tail, extractor, unapply

What is the time and space complexity for this:

```
def isPalindrome[A](x: Seq[A]): Boolean = x match {
  case h +: middle :+ t => h == t && isPalindrome(middle)
  case _ => true
}
```

Does it depend on the implementation of `Seq`? Since `IndexedSeq` should have `O(1)` tail vs `O(n)` for `LinearSeq`s? Is the space complexity is `O(n)` because of the recursive call stack or does Scala does tail call optimization automatically?

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

@tailrec def isPalindrome[A](x: Seq[A]): Boolean = x match {
  case h +: middle :+ t => h == t && isPalindrome(middle)
  case _ => true
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure the complexity depends on the implementation. As to @tailrec, it is used to enforce tail recursion (i.e. Throw a compiler error when something is annotated but not tail recursive) tail recursive functions are optimized automatically. Scala does not have full Tail Call Optimization though.

Comment: According to http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List scala List "has O(1) prepend and head/tail access"  regarding time performance while the space cost of tail is none and I think likewise for head although it is not stated. There is a table of collection time performance characteristics at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html that shows time performance of ArraySeq is same as List for head but Linear in seq length for tail.

Comment: Is there anyway I can keep the same code and have it be O(n) time and O(1) space?

Answer (score 1):

> Does it depend on the implementation of Seq? Since IndexedSeq should have O(1) tail vs O(n) for LinearSeqs?

I would normally assume so however the extractor is actually `O(n)`. The extractor for any `Seq` is `scala.collection.:+` which has `O(n)` for the list up to the last and `O(n)` for the last. The code for those two are the following:

```
  def init: Repr = {
    if (isEmpty) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("empty.init")
    var lst = head
    var follow = false
    val b = newBuilder
    b.sizeHint(this, -1)
    for (x <- this) { // O(n)
      if (follow) b += lst
      else follow = true
      lst = x
    }
    b.result
  }

  def last: A = {
    var lst = head
    for (x <- this) // O(n)
      lst = x
    lst
  }
```

> Is the space complexity is O(n) because of the recursive call stack or does Scala does tail call optimization automatically?

I see that the code does have this optimization.  It makes sense because `t && isPalindrome(middle)` allows Scala to close the current call stack, pass `t` over to the next stack to be `&&`ed with, and hence it being tail-recursion optimisation-able.

#### Constant time matching

Using `Vector` we can achieve `O(1)` time:

```
object ends {
  def unapply[T](t: Vector[T]): Option[(T, Vector[T], T)] =
    if (t.length < 2) None
    else Some((t.head, t.drop(1).dropRight(1), t.last))
}

def isPalindrome[A](x: Vector[A]): Boolean = x match {
  case ends(i, middle, l) => i == l && isPalindrome(middle)
  case _ => true
}
```

Comment: @bjfletcher "O(2n)" isn't really a thing.

Comment: @TravisBrown I find it quite surprising that it does two loops over the sequence and I thought it was worth noting. How'd you write it? "O(n) - it does two loops in fact"? Thanks :)

Comment: How can I keep the same nice recursive code and do it in O(n) time? I know I can ofcourse use IndexedSeqs to quickly look at start and end and keep pointers around but that feels dirtier.. Why isn't there a O(1) time tail extractor?

Comment: @bjfletcher I'd just say something like "and it traverses the sequence twice". As abuses of notation go, "O(2n)" isn't that terrible, I guess, but you're opening yourself to quibbling (from people like me, sorry :)).

Comment: Would you like me to update answer with new extractor ideas? Let me know and I'll do it tomorrow. @Travis, don't be sorry - I enjoy learning how to improve this technical penmanship. :)

Comment: New extractor ideas sounds good! No reason that extractor for tail should be O(n) for sequences that have O(1) tail ?

Comment: @wrick `middle` for `IndexedSeq` is `O(n)`. I've used `Vector` here for `O(1)` pattern matching. See updated answer. :)